# Ford Ranger manual transmission randomly squeals in 5th gear

Tags: ford, clutch, manual-transmission, noise, ranger

My clutch started to slip and was squealing so I had a new clutch, flywheel, slave cylinder, pilot and throw out bearings all replaced. It drives fine, but it randomly makes a loud squeal in fifth gear sometimes. It will stop if I let off the gas and then it drives fine. Was something put on wrong or could it be in the trans?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which I can think of which might be making any noise is the clutch itself. When you get to 5th gear, which I believe is an overdrive gear in the Ranger, you are applying a lot more torque at the clutch. If it wasn't bedded correctly, it could be slipping in this higher gear, thus causing the noise you describe.